# Is using IoC container (such as autofac) to store application settings good practice?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

Before I used to store settings such as connection strings on a settings.json file. Is creating classes like this bad practice?

**Interface**

```
public interface IConnectionString
{
    string Host { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }
    int Port { get; set; }
    string Username { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Converts it to a string that DB will understand
    /// </summary>
    string AsString();
}
```

**Classes**

```
public class MongoDbLocalConnectionString : IConnectionString
{
    public int Port { get => 27017; set { } }

    public string Host { get => "localhost"; set { } }
    public string Password { get => null; set { } }
    public string Username { get => null; set { } }

    public string AsString()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Host))
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached) { Debugger.Break(); }
            ULoggerDefinitions.Logger.Log(LogType.Error, "HBY5-BT7H", "host cannot be null");
            throw new Exception("98NO-KVKR");
        }

        // connect without authenticating
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
        {
            return $"mongodb://{Host}:{Port}";
        }

        // ... etc
    }
}

// Additional connection strings implementing IConnectionString....
public class DebugConnectionString : IConnectionString {
// ... etc
```

Now with autofac it is convenient to select what connection string I want to use. I can do things like:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// register defaults
builder.RegisterType<CoreLogger>().As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>().SingleInstance();

using (var scope = builder.Build().BeginLifetimeScope((ContainerBuilder b) => {

    // register/override dependencies for this
    b.RegisterType<DebugConnectionString>.As<IConnectionString>();

    // can add more registrations...
}))
{
    // connection string will exist only in this scope
}
```

**Having something like this instead of a settings.json file bad practice?**

Comment: I don't get why you would want to replace the settings.json?
You can easily pull connectionsstrings into options from there. _And_ have environmental overrides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think storing sensitive data in code is bad way. With `IConfiguration` you can use not only files but also environment variables (best way for deployment) or user secrets (best way if you don't want to store some protected data in git repository). Also you might want to use `IOptions` [usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Also, you need to re-build your project on any change (against re-run).